# How does short pointer address work in scanf

Tags: c

```
short a,*pt=&a;
printf("%x, %p\n",&a,pt);
scanf("%d",&a);
printf("%x, %p\n",&a,pt);
```

I wanna know what causes the pointer address to change after using the scanf. I know I should use %hd to read in short int but I just wonder what cause the pointer address to change? Also why each run would cause the pointer has different address length to short int's address? I first thought it was because initial read the size of short's address and then int's address, but the difference between two addresses are always different.

Was this simply an undefined behavior?

Comment: "*I know I should use %hd to read in short int but I just wonder what cause the pointer address to change?*" From a C point of view: using a wrong format specifier with `scanf()` is **undefined behavior**, so anything could happen, including the **nasal demons** (google it!)

Comment: On your machine, what **very likely** happens is that your pointer lies directly after your `short` in memory. `scanf()` writes an `int` which is larger than a short, therefore overwriting part of the pointer.

Comment: Btw, I vote to close as "unclear": Asking for **undefined behavior** doesn't make sense and can't be answered (unless you ask about a specific platform and compiler, but than it's still kind of useless)

Comment: @FelixPalmen: Venturing an explanation for undefined behavior instances is always risky and somewhat opinion based, but there is pedagogical value in explaining why this code has undefined behavior, in multiple places, at least 5 IMO.

Comment: "what cause the pointer address to change?" --> UB.  "why each run would cause the pointer has different address length to short int's address?" --> UB. "Was this simply an undefined behavior?" --> Yes.  To ask for an explanation of why a particular UB without providing platform nor compiler version and options is  inefficient for all and too broad.

Answer (score 1):

To read a `short int` with `scanf`, use the `h` size modifier:

```
scanf("%hd",&a);
```

Your code has undefined behavior: `scanf` reads an integer from `stdin` and stores it as an `int` into the address of `a`. Since `a` is a `short`, most likely smaller than an `int` on your architecture, some of the bytes modified by `scanf` belong to another object, maybe the pointer `pt` that you see modified, although it is unlikely because of alignement constraints.

Note also that printing a pointer with `%x` also has undefined behavior and the format `%p` requires a `void *`, which may be passed differently than a `short *`, indeed these types have different representations on some architectures such as older Cray supercomputers.

Here is a less problematic version, with a single instance of undefined behavior:

```
short a, *pt = &a;
printf("%p, %p\n", (void*)&a, (void*)pt);
scanf("%d", &a);
printf("%p, %p\n", (void*)&a, (void*)pt);
```

And here is a correct version that should print the same values:

```
short a, *pt = &a;
printf("%p, %p\n", (void*)&a, (void*)pt);
scanf("%hd", &a);
printf("%p, %p\n", (void*)&a, (void*)pt);
```

Comment: Yes I stated that I know I should use %hd to read short. I just want to ask if there's an explaintion or just an undefined behavior. Thanks.